# mysql var/lib/mysql directory doesn't exist, can't start mysql server

Tags: path, mysql

I have read many a forum post and hopeful solution to the problem I am having with getting my own mysql server to start and work properly, but none so far have worked. Many of the forum posts I've read make reference to a /var/lib/mysql folder, as do some of the errors I receive, such as when I run

```
$ mysqld
```

on Terminal using a Mac and receive the following error

```
2013-06-03 00:40:46 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2013-06-03 00:40:46 1851 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/Alexs-MacBook-Pro-3.lower-test
2013-06-03 00:40:46 1851 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/Alexs-MacBook-Pro-3.lower-test
mysqld: Can't change dir to '/var/lib/mysql/' (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
2013-06-03 00:40:46 1851 [ERROR] Aborting

2013-06-03 00:40:46 1851 [Note] Binlog end
2013-06-03 00:40:46 1851 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

I have deleted everything related to MySQL and reinstalled MySQL, both from a dmg file and from an unzipped tar.gz file from the MySQL downloads page. Nothing has worked. The strange this is that I was using MySQL and the MySQL Workbench only days ago, when suddenly it started giving me this error when I ran the following command

```
$ mysql

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I can't even start the daemon using mysqld_safe... I need a walkthrough of what to do from here to get the MySQL server correctly running again.

Comment: Have you tried to go to System Preferences > (You are gonna see here a icon of MySQL) Click on that > Start Server ?

Comment: Does `/var/lib/mysql` exist?

Answer (score 13):

On a fresh Ubuntu 16, after having done some nonsense, I removed /var/lib/mysql manually. I wanted mariadb and hoped that

```
sudo apt-get remove mariadb-server mariadb-client
```

followed by

```
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server mariadb-client
```

re-creates it, but it didn't.

What helped was

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql-common
```

as this common package seems to be responsible for the directory creation. This took me much longer than needed, as it's package I didn't install explicitly, so I didn't think about removing it (some autoremove could have helped).

Comment: The OP wasn't using Debian.  Good tip for people that are on Debian or Ubuntu and that are using a "mysql-alike" database such as maria or percona

Comment: you are a life savior

Answer (score 3):

I'd try this.

```
mkdir /var/lib/mysql
chown -R mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

I am guessing that you are running mysql as the user "mysql".  If not, either create the user `mysql` and run the mysqld_safe with the option --user="mysql" OR chown the folders to be owned by the user you are running as

Comment: So I checked my /var/lib/mysql directory, and it does exist. use the
    chown -R mysql /var/lib/mysql
command and I still couldn't access it so I made it usable by all by typing
    sudo chmod 777 mysql
Now mysql has access to it, but when I run mysqld it says it can't find the file ".mysql/plugin.frm", and finally ends with a fatal error of "can't find ./mysql/host.frm". It also asked me to run mysql_upgrade to create it. I do THAT and it says "Fatal Error, can't connect through socket /tmp/mysql.sock (2)". Any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you so much yar! @Vorsprung. Around 2 hours, I'm working on this issue. "chown -R mysql /var/lib/mysql" - Its solve my all problems

Comment: **Do not** use things like `chmod -R 777 /var/lib/mysql`, unless you really want to publish all your data. Properly uninstall mysql (including the package `mysql-common`) and re-install it. It creates the directory with right permissions.